# Why does extends return false when comparing two interfaces?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

**Background**

I've been trying to get a better understanding of how `extends` works. I read this excellent [article](https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/) that describes `A extends B` as meaning,

> 'A is a superset of B'

Or

> 'A is a possibly-more-specific version of B'

I also read an SO answer (that i can no longer find) where the author describes `extends` as meaning,

> 'goes into`

All of this helped in my understanding.

**Problem**

I put together some [examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4&ssl=36&ssc=64&pln=36&pc=15#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9hAzgUQB7AgOwCYB4CCANFAEIB8UAvFPlBOltoqVAPxTABOArtAFxQAZgEMANoggBuALAAoUJFgIUDHADk4mGAEtEXbQCNuwbQDcIBYuSpQA2vgC6dVUzskn7LrygCR4qXKBstqYGJwiAMbQALIgAJKhEOHCUZYs1KZw2tgUAN5yUIVQ2HAAynAAthDAABYhAOYAFCFgxgL4AJQCJM4YOMyZ2Ww0PiMAPqQysgC+QRGiwojMsQDCC0sAjFDaFWCiEFWhy-GJyal6nA15BUUl5VW1Dc2YrcACFw1dUB+Y9VD5siKQKgnGq3E4mG2L2MUyBsxmc3WxzWi0QACZtrt9odgMcEmFIhYfvViJhuBUDElroDbmVKtU6r9nq93vpfl9iVAJmSKUl-jdgSCwRCoa9YUV4fC5ApoDKttR4Eg0H08MTiMSKAB6TUcHgBeTgWWGjEK5TKxi4NVQADkICQ1q1Or8EimMo4hoAzDZFSoVbhbfb1Wz6o7dbxXYb3ZAACzes0uXBeCDEAxwOD7YSYUNJ6WRmUAVjjSoTqfTEEzxCToewun0RgwzCTXKEYgkUAAtELgODMMxSxnMLnFDKAGxF32MDRaWuXetmCz98uYYjOiCh1dBN0ygDs4-NOFwqyRG2IR9RaMdOYNw8NAA49wmz0s0aeQCjNo6N7Ih0bIABOB8-VifEkkJS1gzIV8QLOIlg1JclKU4Mh11baBO3rbZnEgCIMGwMMIFYH8owgDYAAZAItYDTjAq0eUQyCoCogkUlgy5fmQqBtRbfwiLleUlGLICTmY844KgOiqSg6iWPAtiSXEhCqWzPVeMNDYTQEicDyY0CZNoxSkKkkTWIaeDeU4ZsADFuEwHDtE0DiuKvVTIA2L1TUEyi32PIzdNEuTHJ1K8tzU2MPK0vAdJg2Srlfd9EA2ZTeBckjC3C-dIu81ET0Y4S-JM34zPopKIBSjYx3Sx88ui-TzIYp8EpQnjv2vX8SN3SqhPil9cugmiIKaiQyvvTqvL6vSILipEL04oKVNa4iNgA0btKy59fJqsSJKQkqUrRciVsy8b-NMhS6qm89dpaoA) (in the TS playground) with a utility type to see for myself, but found one case that i didn't expect to return false.

```
type DoesExtend<A, B> = A extends B ? true : false;


interface MyInterface<A, B = void> {
    doSomething(input: A): B extends void ? A : A | B;
}

class MyClass1 implements MyInterface<string> {
    doSomething(input: string): string {
        return input;
    }
}

class MyClass2 implements MyInterface<string, number> {
    doSomething(input: string): string | number {
        return input;
    }
}
```

The following comparisons all returned what i expected,

```
DoesExtend<MyClass1, MyClass2> //true
DoesExtend<MyClass2, MyClass1> //false

DoesExtend<MyClass1, MyInterface<string>> // true
DoesExtend<MyInterface<string>, MyClass1> // true
DoesExtend<MyClass1, MyInterface<string, number>> // true
DoesExtend<MyInterface<string, number>, MyClass1> // false

DoesExtend<MyClass2, MyInterface<string>> // false
DoesExtend<MyInterface<string>, MyClass2> // true
DoesExtend<MyClass2, MyInterface<string, number>> // true
DoesExtend<MyInterface<string, number>, MyClass2> // true
```

But when comparing `MyInterface` with `MyInterface` one result was unexpected,

```
DoesExtend<MyInterface<string>, MyInterface<string, number>> // false - but i expected true?
DoesExtend<MyInterface<string, number>, MyInterface<string>> // false
DoesExtend<MyInterface<string, number>, MyInterface<string, number>> // true
DoesExtend<MyInterface<string, number>, MyInterface<string, number | Function>> // true
```

**Question**

So given that the following are true,

```
DoesExtend<MyClass1, MyClass2>
DoesExtend<MyClass1, MyInterface<string, number>>
DoesExtend<MyInterface<string>, MyClass2>
```

please can someone explain why the following - which would appear to me to be equivalent to the examples above and that i expected to be true - is false?

```
DoesExtend<MyInterface<string>, MyInterface<string, number>>
```